# VS Online TFS Remove Folder and Start Over?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Just started working with TFS / VS Online and managed to screw up the folder structure. I've read a dozen or so posts and it sounds scary to try to fix, so looking for guidance.

I decided to move the folder on my local machine and apparently overlooked some un-mapping chores. So when I checked in my solution the next time I managed to create an entire solution *inside* the existing solution. My instinct is to un-map my local drive and delete the entire folder structure from TFS and start fresh. I share the project with only one other person and I figured we could coordinate the effort. After reading many of the posts it sounds like I could end up creating a huge mess.

What's the recommended approach for cleaning up my mess, or is it better to live with it?

Comment: Back up your code (if any) that you want to keep and delete the folder(s) from source. You might also investigate destroy but for now delete should do.

Comment: Thanks John, thanks Mike. Tomorrow's to-do.